# Как добавить обводку тексту?

Tags: android, xml

В андроид приложении необходимо добавить обводку для текста. Можно ли это выполнить прямо из студии, не используя добавление шрифтов?

Comment: Нормальный вопрос, не надо минусовать

Comment: *обводка* - это не *тень* случайно?

Comment: нет, тень размывается. нужна обводка

Comment: @ДаниилКЕТОВ Обводки нету, только тень, её же как и обводку можно использовать

Answer (score 1):

```
android:background="@drawable/redframe"
```

Здесь redframe - растягивающаяся рамка, файл redframe.9.png в папке drawable

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, Вам будет полезной [библиотека MagicTextView](https://github.com/m5/MagicTextView), в которой реализуется в том числе и обводка текста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]